# Where to begin troubleshooting Windows Explorer non-responsiveness

Tags: windows-10

Context: Windows 10, Dual boot Ubuntu 16.04, SSD: 18GB Free in Windows partition, 16GB RAM,

Attempts to open the files, including simple .txt files in Sublime, from the Explorer file manager are painfully slow (30+ seconds).  This also includes Libre-Office documents, Adobe .pdf, etc.  Therefore, I do not think this is a problem at the application level.  Sometimes the Explorer windows will grey-out and the title bar of the window will display (Not Responding)

It is not uncommon for the title bar to display: **(Not Responding)** immediately after selecting a file with the right mouse button.

If I drop and drag the text file into Sublime, then it is open immediately.

Where would one begin to troubleshoot to determine the root cause of the problem: is there a specific (measurable) test that can be performed?  Hopefully, this is common problem that has been resolved under different nomenclature.

Comment: Starting by error checking the Windows partition(s) seems a good idea. If the same or similar issue is experienced in Ubuntu I would be considering a drive replacement at this point.

Comment: Sounds like an overly bloated anti-virus. What are you running?

Comment: Running Windows defender.   Ubuntu partition works like a champ.

Comment: Process Monitor - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon with the Duration column added might provide some insight.